# UWP Bluetooth finding devices takes long time

Tags: bluetooth, uwp, windows-10-universal, rfcomm

I'm trying (like many others) to make an app which initially should be able to detect all visible bluetooth (RFComm) devices (both unpaired and paired, connected and not connected) and list them on screen.
After that it sould also be able to pair with a selected device.

I'm currently at the point when I'm trying to understand how bluetooth works in Windows 10 at all. I found that bluetooth devices are viewed as devices that are connected to pc like keyboards, mice, usb-hubs etc and if I want to see bluetooth devices one of the most convenient ways is to use Deviceinformation.FindAllAsync() method.

I used some sample code to find devices, first try being:

```
selector = BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
        var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);
        foreach (var device in devices)
        {
            var bluetoothDevice = await BluetoothDevice.FromIdAsync(device.Id);
            if (bluetoothDevice != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(bluetoothDevice.BluetoothAddress);
            }
            Debug.WriteLine(device.Id);
            foreach (var property in device.Properties)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("   " + property.Key + " " + property.Value);
            }
        }
```

This method finds none of the bluetooth devices that are near my device.

If i change first line from:

```
selector = BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
```

to something like this:

```
selector = BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(false);
```

it is able to finally locate all visible unpaired devices and FindAllAsync takes a whopping 30 seconds to find all of these.

Here question arises: how to find all devices that are visible regardless of their pairing state and how to speed up 30-seconds search time to much less ?

In the end I have to find 1 specific bluetooth 2.0 device and connect to it. How this can be done after I have found it using FindAllAsync?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `FindAllAsync` you should create a `DeviceWatcher`, add handlers for the events it exposes, and then call `Start()`. This will not only give you some initial results much faster, it will also let you react to devices disappearing.

`FindAllAsync` takes a long time because it has to wait for a timeout to occur (indicating no more devices are around) and cannot return any partial results.

Comment: I have used DeviceWatcher. Device information of a device saved locally using OnDeviceAdded event, and called FromIdAsync(device.Id) but FromIdAsync API returned null. If I enumerate the device FindAllAsync and then call FromIdAsync(), result is success.